# item shows individually

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to make the `show()` individually, once I clicked the, show, all `.whateverever` class(es) are opened.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function excerpt(text, len) {
        return text.substring(0, len) + "&hellip;" + '<span>Show</span>';
    }

    var $div = $('.container');
    $div.each(function() {
        var $p = $(this).find("p:first");
        var theExcerpt = excerpt($p.text(), 230);
        $p.data('html', $p.html()).html(theExcerpt);
    });

    $('span').click(function() {
        var isHidden = $(this).text() == 'Show';
        var $p = $(this).parent();
        var theExcerpt = excerpt($p.text(), 230);
        $p.html(isHidden ? $p.data('html') : theExcerpt);
        $('.whateverever').show();
        $(this).remove();
    });

});​
```

Please check online SAMPLE: http://jsfiddle.net/M6wzh/6/
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function excerpt(text, len) {
        return text.substring(0, len) + "&hellip;" + '<span>Show</span>';
    }

    var $div = $('.container');
    $div.each(function() {
        var $p = $(this).find("p:first");
        var theExcerpt = excerpt($p.text(), 230);
        $p.data('html', $p.html()).html(theExcerpt);
    });

    $('span').click(function() {
        var isHidden = $(this).text() == 'Show';
        var $p = $(this).parent();
        var theExcerpt = excerpt($p.text(), 230);
        $p.html(isHidden ? $p.data('html') : theExcerpt);
        $p.next().show();//the div you're looking for is the next sibling of the parent p
        $(this).remove();
    });

});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/M6wzh/7/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.whateverever', this).show();
```

instead of

```
$('.whateverever').show();
```

should get you on your way.

Comment: The target `.whateverever` is not a descendant of the span

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$('span').click(function() {
    var isHidden = $(this).text() == 'Show';
    var $p = $(this).parent();
    var theExcerpt = excerpt($p.text(), 230);
    $p.html(isHidden ? $p.data('html') : theExcerpt);
    $(this).next(".whateverever").show();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M6wzh/8/)

Answer (score 0):

have u use .closet() of jquery before this.
just little edit in your code

```
   $('.whateverever').show();
replace this line by        
   $.closest('.whateverever').show();
  and check.
```

Comment: i have tried it from the jsfiddle and then post the answer. and it working